# Code Refactoring JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for my menu system. It works just perfect. It's a jQuery sliding menu (youtube kind of slide in menu).

I was wondering if there is any other better way I would written the jQuery code to achieve the same result.(Code refactoring).

```
var main = function() {

    if(!$('.menu li span').hasClass('closed')){
        $(".menu li").find('span').addClass('closed');
        $('.menu li').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('.closed').show();
          })
         $('.menu li ').mouseleave(function() {
           $(this).find('.closed').hide();
          });
    } 

    $(".icon-menu").click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();

    if($("body").hasClass("opened")){
        $(".menu").animate({
            width: "59px"
        }, 300);
        $("body").removeClass('opened');
        $(".menu li").find('span').addClass('closed');
        $('.menu li').find('span').fadeOut(300);    

    }else{
        $(".menu").animate({
            width: "193px"
        }, 300);
            $("body").addClass('opened');
            $(".menu li").find('span').removeClass('closed');
            $('.menu li span').show();
        }

    });

    $('html').click(function() {
        //Hide the menus if visible
        if($("body").hasClass("opened")){
            $(".menu").animate({
                width: "59px"
            }, 300);
            $("body").removeClass('opened');
            $(".menu li").find('span').addClass('closed');
            $('.menu li').find('span').fadeOut(300);    
        } 
    });


}; 
 $(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: This would be better placed in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Barmar Close it as off-topic because it's off-topic here. Whether or not it's on-topic on other sites like Code Review is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mast It's just a suggestion.

Comment: There's no reason you can't provide a helpful comment (include where it might be better asked) when you vote to close, if you are so inclined.

Comment: On the general topic of refactoring -- when, why, how -- https://www.agiledeveloper.com/presentations/how_to_approach_refactoring_2up.pdf

Comment: @Barmar Nothing wrong with placing it as a suggestion like Daenu did. That's something else than voting to close because of suggestion. If you happen to VTC ánd you want to make a suggestion, separate those.

Comment: I don't see why I can't do both in one step. I voted to close, and my close reason was because it belongs somewhere else, not here.

Comment: @Barmar would it be better if I delete the thread from here? I can do so. No need for anyone to be rude.

Comment: You could flag it and ask the moderators to migrate it.